# How do you close apps in Android so they aren't taking up resources?

Tags: task-management, resource-monitoring, home-button

This may sound silly but it's a good point. In apps such as web browsers pressing the back key only navigates the browser back to the previous page. Pressing the home key makes an app disappear, but isn't it still running in the back ground? So for apps like web browsers where pressing the back key doesn't close them how do you close them when you want to change applications and not have an unused one taking resources?

Isn't it a bit rediculous that there's no built in way in android to exit an app?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced task killer is very simple, light(< 300kb), and can be placed as an widget to kill all the running process in a single touch.

Also if you have developers options enabled in your phone you can select the number of background process limit or what to do when user leaves a process.

Comment: Thanks can you elaborate? I installed advanced task killer but don't see any option to kill all processes at once. There's a few I would like to leave running as exceptions e.g. antivirus, vpn client. I do have developer options enabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any task killer or task manager for it.

Or simply you can go to

System ->Application -> Running -> select app and click on stop.

if android v 3.0 + then

just long press Home key On lenovo long press menu key and just left or right 
slide you app it will get killed...

ok...